# HTML border below text box

Tags: html, css

How do I make the bottom border land exactly below the textbox?

```css
div {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #354458;
}
p {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #354458;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 190px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', courier, monospace
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>How do I remove the margin below here?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add margin-bottom:0px; to the P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove browser's default margin of your `p` tag which in my case is

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
```

by setting `margin-bottom: 0;` or just removing all the margins by setting them to 0.

In order to get more consistent cross-browser layout you should consider using CSS reset solution, for example [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

```css
p {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #354458;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 190px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', courier, monospace;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
div {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #354458
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>How do remove the margin below here?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`p` tag by default will have some margins around it. Make it zero so that border sticks to the bottom.

Added `margin-bottom:0px;`

```css
div {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #354458;
}
p {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #354458;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 190px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', courier, monospace;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Margin from below this has been removed!!</p>
</div>
```